# How to pronounce 100ish?

Tags: pronunciation

How do you pronounce 100ish and similar words?

> a hundred-ish ?

Comment: Please don't use comments to post answers

Answer (score 4):

Yes -- just pronounce the number as normal, plus the suffix.